# mypy Cannot find implementation or library stub for module

Tags: python, mypy

I have:

```
foo/
├── __init__.py
├── bar.py
└── baz
    ├── __init__.py
    └── alice.py
```

In `bar.py`, I import Alice, which is an empty class with nothing in it but the `name` attribute set to `"Alice"`.

```
from baz.alice import Alice

a = Alice()
print(a.name)
```

This runs properly:

```
$ python foo/bar.py
Alice
```

But mypy complains:

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.910
$ mypy --strict .
foo/bar.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "baz.alice"
foo/bar.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 6 source files)
```

Why is mypy complaining?

Comment: Does it still complain if you fully qualify the import `from foo.baz.alice import Alice`?

Comment: mypy becomes happy in that case, but then the python interpreter raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'`. Maybe I'm missing some other change to fix that?

Comment: @TomHuibregtse when you run `python foo/bar.py`, your `PYTHONPATH` does not include the directory where `foo` is. In your `foo/bar.py`, add a `print(sys.path)`. You'll see it includes the `foo/` directory, but it won't include the directory where `foo` itself is (one level up). That means Python has no way of resolving the `foo` package. So you need to add that directory to your `PYTHONPATH` env variable if you really want to run the script from the `foo` folder.

Comment: Paul41's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

mypy has its own search path for imports and does not resolve imports exactly as Python does and it isn't able to find the `baz.alice` module. Check the documentation listed in the error message, specifically the section on [How imports are found:](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#how-imports-are-found)

> The rules for searching for a module `foo` are as follows:
>
> The search looks in each of the directories in the search path (see
> above) until a match is found.
>
> 1. If a package named `foo` is found (i.e. a directory foo containing an `__init__.py` or `__init__.pyi` file) that’s a match.
> 2. If a stub file named `foo.pyi` is found, that’s a match.
> 3. If a Python module named `foo.py` is found, that’s a match.

The documentation also states that this in the section on [Mapping file paths to modules](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#mapping-file-paths-to-modules):

> For each file to be checked, `mypy` will attempt to associate the file
> (e.g. `project/foo/bar/baz.py`) with a fully qualified module name (e.g.
> `foo.bar.baz`).

There's a few ways to solve this particular issue:

1. As paul41 mentioned in his comment, one option to solve this issue is by providing the fully qualified import (`from foo.baz.alice import Alice`), and then running from a top-level module (a `.py` file in the root level).
2. You could add a `# type: ignore` to the import line.
3. You can edit the `MYPYPATH` variable to point to the `foo` directory:

```sh
(venv) (base) ➜ mypy foo/bar.py --strict
foo/bar.py:3: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "baz.alice"
foo/bar.py:3: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
(venv) (base) ➜ export MYPYPATH=foo/     
(venv) (base) ➜ mypy foo/bar.py --strict
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `# type: ignore` be undesired if I still wanted to have type checking for my use of the `foo.baz.alice` module in `foo.bar`? Also, I like your `PYTHONPATH` solution from above. It allows me to use fully qualified module names. Poetry takes care of adding `foo/` to `PYTHONPATH` as seen by `sys.path` output.

Comment: @TomHuibregtse yeah for sure, I'm just giving you ways to solve your error. Ideally you don't want to have to be disabling mypy type checking for specific lines unless you really had to.